# "And" keyword gets attached to preceding argument, gets misread by TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the TikZ code of my tex file, I have a line

`\path[draw=cyan] (\xOne+\xTwo+\xThree,2*\yOne+\yTwo+\yThree) ellipse (\xThree  and \yOne);`

which triggers the following error during compilation :

`Package PGF Math Error : Unknown operator 'a' or 'an' (in '28.4527ptand 56.90549pt')`

So, it seems that when `\xThree` is expanded, the following `and` keyword gets mistakenly attached to it.  Adding more blank spaces did not solve the problem. How can I fix this ?

Here is the complete file :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\myUnit

\setlength{\myUnit}{1cm}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xOne}{\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xTwo}{2*\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xThree}{\myUnit}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yOne}{2*\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yTwo}{\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yThree}{\myUnit}%
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) (2*\xOne+2*\xTwo+2*\xThree,\yOne+\yTwo+\yThree);
 \path[draw=cyan] (0,0)
 -- ++(\xOne,\yOne)
 -- ++(\xTwo,\yTwo)
 -- ++(\xThree,-\yThree) 
 -- ++(\xThree,\yThree) 
 -- ++(\xTwo,-\yTwo)
 -- ++(\xOne,-\yOne)
 -- cycle
 ;
 \path[draw=cyan] (\xOne+\xTwo+\xThree,2*\yOne+\yTwo+\yThree) ellipse (\xThree  and \yOne);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  Normal text here
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention in your previous question: `tikz` loads `xcolor`, so there's no need to add `\usepackage{xcolor}` explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TikZ parser expects a space before the `and` keyword but `LaTeX` removes spaces after macros. Try using the more explicit syntax:

```
\path[draw=cyan] ellipse [x radius=\xThree, y radius=\yOne];
```

Although you can use the somewhat uglier:

```
\path[draw=cyan] ellipse ({\xThree} and \yOne);
```

Comment: Both work. Personally I prefer the (shorter) ugly version :-)